# Load GEBCO data for making bathymetry relief plots

Tags: import, geography

Does Mathematica understand GEBCO? Is it able to download GEBCO bathymetry datasets and use that data to make relief plots?

Comment: Are you asking if Mathematica can handle the data?  If yes, have you tried downloading and importing it yourself? Or are you asking if Mathematica has this as a built-in data source?  There's `GeoElevationData` but I don't know its data source.

Comment: The current data provided by GeoElevationData is in fact based on the 30" grid in GEBCO 2008. GeoGraphics with geo styling "ReliefMap" produces maps using that data.